# Show/Hide method in PyQt5 multiplying QLineEdit execution

Tags: python, pyqt5, hide, show

So I've got a problem with PyQt5 python -> show() and hide() methon are multiplying execution of QlineEdit and it's def assigned.

For example when I'm clicking on BO_Button, the QLineEdit "number_InputField" shows up and it's okay - providing number to field, clicking 'enter' on keyboard and def 'access' is executed. However if I click on BO_Button, and then click on share_Button, and once again click on BO_Button (which caused show() method on number_InputField -> hide() -> and show() once again), then when I provide number to field and press enter, the function 'access' will be executed twice (if I do same procedure but show/hide 3 times, then function 'access' will be executed thrice etc...)

Is there any solution for this?

```
    self.number_InputField.hide()
    self.share_InputField.hide()
    self.BO_Button.clicked.connect(self.userInputFieldNumber)
    self.share_Button.clicked.connect(self.userInputField_Share)

def userInputFieldNumber(self):
    self.number_InputField.show()
    self.share_InputField.hide()
    self.numberInputField.returnPressed.connect(self.handleNumber)

def userInputField_Share(self):
    self.number_InputField.hide()
    self.share_InputField.show()
    self.XInputField.returnPressed.connect(self.handleX)

def handleNumber(self):
    global number
    numberNumber = self.numberInputField.text()
    self.access()
```

Comment: Every time you connect a signal to a function you will cause the function to be called *as many times it has been connected*. Either disconnect the previously connected function, or use a dedicated function that decides what to do based on the context (your example is insufficient to really understand what that would be, so it's up to you). Also, don't use globals.

Comment: @musicamante I tried disconnect method but it disconnected permanently my "self.BO_Button.clicked.connect(self.userInputFieldNumber)" so it's not what I wanted sadly. Now if I click on BO_Button, number_InputField will show (wich ich QLineEdit) and after providing value there and press 'enter' it will execute once. But if I click on BO_Button twice and then provide value in number_InputField and click 'enter' then def handleNumber will be executed twice... But I want it to be executed only once

Comment: Obviously, that's not the signal you should disconnect, but the `returnPressed` one. Use a try/except block to disconnect (because the first time it won't be connected yet) or the same for a `Qt.UniqueConnection` type, which prevents connecting the same signal/slot pair more than once.

Comment: Now it works like a charm when disconnect() has been implemented into def with returnPressed! Issue solved thanks to @musicamante :) Much thanks man!